# ML Modeling Recommendation for Predicting Snake Encounters in Historical Journey Data

Tags: time-series, classification, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, hybrid

I have a dataset consisting of historical journey data where individuals travel from point A to point B. During their journeys, they may encounter varying numbers of animal sightings, including snakes. The dataset includes attributes such as time, attribute_1, attribute_2, attribute_3, attribute_4, and a binary label indicating whether a snake was seen or not.

My objective is to create a website that can predict, based on a person's ID and their journey from point X to point Y, whether they are likely to encounter a snake during their next step. I want to choose the most suitable ML modeling approach for this task.

Considering the dynamic nature of the data, the need for real-time predictions, and the potential relevance of the previous snake sightings as additional information, I would like recommendations on which ML modeling techniques to explore. Additionally, I have additional attributes (attribute_1, attribute_2, etc.) that could potentially contribute to the prediction accuracy.

What ML modeling approaches would be most appropriate for this problem? Are there specific algorithms, architectures, or techniques that would be well-suited to handle this type of sequential prediction task?

Can the problem be solved by considering it as a time series classification problem and using the techniques such as LSTM RNN or HMM?

I would appreciate any insights, advice, or references to relevant research papers or tutorials that can help me make an informed decision.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

P.S.
The example of the data structure:

| id | time/step | attribute_1 | attribute_2 | attribute_3 | attribute_4 | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | b | j | 10 | 105 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | b | h | 12 | 45 | 0 |
| 1 | 10 | b | g | 12 | 454 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | y | j | 4 | 54 | 1 |
| 2 | 9 | y | m | 7 | 65 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 | x | l | 6 | 76 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 | x | r | 99 | 99 | 0 |
| 3 | 6 | x | e | 88 | 8 | 0 |
| 3 | 9 | x | w | 65 | 45 | 0 |
| 3 | 10 | x | f | 44 | 56 | 1 |
| 3 | 11 | x | h | 33 | 45 | 0 |

As can be seen each person might encounter a different number of animals, but what we know this number wouldn't be greater than 25. It depends on from and to where he/she travels. Label 0 means he/she sees an animal but it is not a snake, and 1 shows he/she sees a snake in that certain time/step.

This prediction is important because in the live system if we predict that the person will see the snake in the next step of his/her journey then we can notify him/her beforehand.